# stimulusjs get all values as array

Tags: stimulusjs

I just need get all values how to get it ?

```
export default class extends Controller {

    static values = {
        test: 123,
        path: String,
        createUrl: String,
        mappedClasses: Array,
        columnDefs: Array,
        defaultSort: Object
    };

    connect() {

       

        console.log('config',{
            testOneValue: this.testValue,
            testPathValue: this.pathValue,
            values1: this.constructor.values,
            values2: Object.values(this.constructor.values),
        });
```

this give my

```
Object { testOneValue: 123, testPathValue: "/app/educalendarevent/list?urltarget=crud_63c1225deae26&_list_mode=json", values1: {…}, values2: (6) […] }
​
testOneValue: 123
​
testPathValue: "/app/educalendarevent/list?urltarget=crud_63c1225deae26&_list_mode=json"
​
values1: Object { test: 123, path: String(), createUrl: String(), … }
​​
columnDefs: function Array()
​​
createUrl: function String()
​​
defaultSort: function Object()
​​
mappedClasses: function Array()
​​
path: function String()
​​
test: 123
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
values2: Array(6) [ 123, String(), String(), … ]
```